# Makefile eval function causing unexpected end of file

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to increment a Makefile variable with eval function inside a rule (to do a fancy loading bar), by doing

```
$(eval COUNTER=$(shell echo $$(($(COUNTER) + 1))))
```

I found on internet that this is working for some people but this line causes me a Syntax Error: unexpected end of file, what should I do to increment my counter? Are there some non-horrific alternatives to this function, or a way to avoid this unexpected end of file? thanks for your help
Here is the entire Makefile I'm working on

```
SHELL =     /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES = .c .h .o

NAME =      Necklace

SRCD =      src
INCD =      inc
OBJD =      .obj

SRC =       $(addsuffix $(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES)),\
            main\
            necklace\
            utils)
INC =       $(addsuffix $(word 2, $(.SUFFIXES)),\
            necklace)
OBJ =       $(SRC:$(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES))=$(word 3, $(.SUFFIXES)))

CC =        gcc
CFLAGS =    -Wall\
            -Werror\
            -Wextra\
            -I $(INCD)

COUNT =     $(shell cat file.count 2>/dev/null)
COMPILED =  $(shell echo $$(($(shell ls src/*$(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES)) | wc -l | tr -d ' ') - $(COUNT))))

define set
set = $(eval $1 := $2)

ifeq ($(COUNT),)
all:
    echo $(words $(SRC)) > file.count && $(MAKE) -n | grep $(CC) | wc -l | tr -d ' ' > tmp.txt && rm -f file.count && echo $$(($$(cat tmp.txt) - 1)) > file.count && make
else
all:  $(NAME)
endif

$(NAME): $(addprefix $(OBJD)/, $(OBJ)) | $(addprefix $(INCD)/, $(INC))
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJD):
    mkdir $@

$(OBJD)/%.o: $(SRCD)/%.c | $(OBJD)
    @printf '\r\033[2KCompiling [' && sh prc.sh $(COMPILED) $(COUNT) && printf ']' && $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ && $(eval COMPILED:=$(shell echo $$(($(COMPILED) + 1)))) #Syntax Error is here

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJD)

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish, and give a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? (You've been told about this before.)

Comment: (I strongly suspect the problem is that you're trying to use Make syntax where you ought to use shell syntax, but I can't show that without context.)

Comment: @Beta I know that the problem comes from this command, the syntax error doesn't happen when I remove this so i thought it was useless to give the entire makefile, I'll update the post

Comment: What you want to do can be done, but you'll need a very different design. The shell commands in a rule have no effect on Make variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by writing and reading the variable into a file instead of using Make variables